# VBA Macro not Auto-Updating Cells

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, disabled-input

I have a sheet that calculates a few key financial variables based on one cell changing (the assumptions are pre-calced but each time the cell changes Excel needs to calculate, usually each one runs super fast).

Using an ActiveX combo box (to allow user control/searchability, etc.) I allow a user to change the cell B1:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("B1").Value = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2
End Sub
```

The current problem I am trying to solve is attempting to batch these so I can run a user-defined list iteratively.

In the example below (this is not the end result what I want, just proof of concept that I can easily change cell B1), I am attempting to change cell B1 to values 1, then 2, then 3 and seeing what the results are and will later adapt this to be more flexible than just 1, 2, 3

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 1 To 3
Application.EnableEvents = False
Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("B1").Value = counter
Worksheets("MOBCashFlow").Calculate
Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Calculate

Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("A2").Value = counter
Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("F5").Value
Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("C2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("F6").Value
Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("D2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("G5").Value
Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("E2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("G6").Value
Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("F2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("J5").Value
Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Next counter
End Sub
```

The results (shown below):

```
3   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   758.129033
2   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   758.129033
1   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   $10,134,808.14  $9,194,031.64   758.129033
```

shows that the underlying cell either isn't changing or is changing and is being overwritten by the prior macro (those values are the correct values for the item chosen in the combo box). I'm looking for any creative solutions to manually overwrite that B1 cell which is linked to a ComboBox.

Thank you.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False`  this setting is persistent: it won't turn itself back on once your Sub exits - you have to reset it in your code.  You can try `CalculateFull` instead of `Calculate` - difficult to know which one you might need without knowing how your formulas are set up.

Comment: In the above example, I changed the code to better highlight what the issue is:  
`Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("A2").Value = Counter` to  
`Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("A2").Value = Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Range("B1").Value`  
and it still returns the exact same result. B1 in "Hurdle Evaluation"  is either not changing or the previous macro mentioned above is impacting it. I also tried removing the enableevents flag and tried CalculateFull and CalculateFullRebuild to no avail

Comment: Which sheet is active when this runs?

Comment: 'IterateNPV' is the activesheet that contains the macro. Meant to add that the first column in the edited example isn't 1, 2, 3 as example above but is 4356 4356 4356 indicating that cell B1 isn't changing from that macro

Comment: I can't explain what you're seeing based on the provided code. `counter` *must* be changing in the loop, but the value 4356 can't have come from the code you posted.

Comment: The 4356 comes from what is in the combo box that is determining B1 in the _previous_ macro up above. So because the combobox has an active selection, B1 appers to be locked to that number. I am trying to find a way to disable the first sub listed:  
`Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("B1").Value = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2
End Sub  `

Comment: If you delete the combobox does it work?

Comment: Yes, if I delete the combobox the code works. I want to have the combobox exist where the user is able to change the cell B1 so it's a mandatory functionality (although I'm totally open to other solutions around how to achieve that)  
  
Thank you so much for your help so far :)

Comment: Is your combobox linked to B1 (via Properties >> LinkedCell)?  If yes then that's your problem.  Clear that link and it should work: you're already updating the cell via the Click handler, so it doesn't need to be directly linked.  BTW `EnableEvents` doesn't affect ActiveX control events, so setting that to False doesn't help here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no linked cell in the properties but there are a bunch of other properties that could be the culprit that I haven't investigated yet. Will spend some time looking there

Comment: Also it might be nice to show numbers ascending instead of descending. If that is your case change `For counter = 1 to 3` into `For counter = 1 to 3 step -1`

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution that works but still unsure why it works
Instead of linking to the cell changes ("B1") I changed it to change the index:

```
For counter = 1 To 3
Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").ComboBox1.ListIndex = counter
Worksheets("MOBCashFlow").Calculate
Worksheets("Hurdle Evaluation").Calculate

Worksheets("IterateNPV").Range("A2").Value = counter
Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Next counter
End Sub
```